# Let $f(x)=x^2+bx+4$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. For each $b \in \mathbb{R}$, factor $f(x)$ into a product of irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that for a polynomial to be irreducible, this means that if it is factored then one of the factors has to be a unit. I am confused by what this question is asking because there are an infinite number of "$b$"s in  $\mathbb{R}$ and so I don't understand how I can factor the polynomial since $b$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Use the discriminant. In this case $\Delta=b^2-16$.

Comment: If $-4 < b < 4$ then $x^2 + bx + 4$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. For example, when $b=0$, you have $x^2+4$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I am not quite sure how I would use the discriminant. Could you possibly give me a further hint?

Comment: @FlybyNight So that takes care of -4<b<4, so all I need to do is figure out how to factor for b<-4 and b>4 right?

Comment: I'm not sure. The wording of the question makes it seem impossible. For example, when $b=0$, you can't factor it over $\mathbb{R}$, unless they mean $1 \times (x^2 + 4)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known (from highschool, perhaps?) that a polynomial $p(X)=X^2+bX+c$ admits real roots iff $\Delta(p)=b^2-4c$ is nonnegative. More precisely, if the discriminant is negative, we have complex conjugate roots, if it is null we have a doulbe real root, and if it is positive, we have two distinct real roots.

Comment: So we need only to show the factorization for f(x) when -4<b<4?

Comment: Pedro, this isn't correct. If $\Delta < 0$ then you have complex conjugate roots. If $\Delta =0$ you have a single, repeated real root. If $\Delta > 0$ you have two, distinct real roots.

Comment: @FlybyNight I meant to write "nonnegative" and ended up writing "nonzero." =)

Comment: I understand where there are real roots, but I don't understand how to factor the polynomial still

Answer (score 0):

Use the [general formula for quadratic factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_factorization):

$$f(x) = x^2 + bx + 4 = \underbrace{\left(x-\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 16}}{2}\right)}_{g_1(x)}\underbrace{\left(x-\frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2 - 16}}{2}\right)}_{g_2(x)}$$

**Restriction:** $g_1(x), g_2(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ requires that $\sqrt{b^2 - 16} \in \mathbb{R}$ which gives $|b| \ge 4$.